# Encryption in C# and Decryption in Java, getting PaddingException

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I have a c# code which does the encryption and a java code which decrypt, but in Java I get
"Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption".

But if I encrypt in JAVA and decrypt in JAVA , it works fine. Please help I am stuck since a week.

I read PKCS5Padding and PKCS7Padding both are same in JAVA, is it true?
to try with PKCS7Padding in Java, I used bouncy Castle but that gave below error
" BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted"

C# Encryption Logic:

```
string Encrypt(string textToEncrypt, string key)
{
RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
rijndaelCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
rijndaelCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

rijndaelCipher.KeySize = 0x80;
rijndaelCipher.BlockSize = 0x80;
byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0x10];
int len = pwdBytes.Length;
if (len > keyBytes.Length)
{
len = keyBytes.Length;
}
Array.Copy(pwdBytes, keyBytes, len);
rijndaelCipher.Key = keyBytes;
rijndaelCipher.IV = keyBytes;
ICryptoTransform transform = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt);
return Convert.ToBase64String(transform.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length)); 
}
```

Java Decryption Logic

```
public String decryptInputData(String encryptedRequest, String key1)  {

        byte[] cipherData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedRequest);
        byte[] keyByte = key1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] IV=new byte[16];   

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(IV);

        Cipher aesCBC;
        try {
            aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            aesCBC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            byte[] decryptedData = aesCBC.doFinal(cipherData);
            return new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException |InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException |IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Test Data:
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

Key:TL3U2HAQJZ79F8O5X4CNW6S10IEKGPYB

PlainText:
Salutation=MRS|Customer_Name=ITMSYAR EBMEEN|Address=ABCD EFG~WERT|City=GHTTG|Pin_Code=310012|State=WERY|DOB=1900-02-19|Gender=F|Mobile_Number=010007000007|Nationality=IN|Email_Address=ABCDEFG@GMAIL.COM|Marital_Status=Y|Occupation_Type=Housewife|PAN_Number=AOIPM1619P|Nominee_Name=|Nominee_DOB=|Relationship_of_Nominee=|Timestamp=7/26/2022 11:06:16 AM|Website_Ref_No=1zEeSs97MAao5UIi|CRM_Lead_Id=9121421421|Source_Id=MB_LoggedIn|Referral_Code=123456|utm_source=|utm_medium=|utm_campaign=|Product_Name=Group Active Health Plan|Partner_Name=ABCD|SP_Code=|LG_SOL_ID=002|Producer_Code=202324134|EBCC_Flag=N|Scheme_Code=FSGSW|CKYC_NO=|Acc_No=1234567889|Acc_Type=Main|

Comment: The default padding mode in c# is different from java.  You need to change the padding mode in either c# or java so they are compatible.  Use something like  encryptedSymmetricKey = rsa.Encrypt(aes.Key, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);

Comment: @jdweng: The problem here is I can't change the logic in c#. Any other pointers to fix the issue?

Comment: Both codes use an identical padding, that is PKCS#7 padding (which is called PKCS#5 padding in the Java world for historical reasons). The use of `RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1` makes no sense for AES.

Comment: The C# code applies the key as IV, the Java code uses a zero IV (both are insecure). Apart from that, decryption works on my machine with a 16 bytes key. What is missing in the Java code is the (insecure) key correction. The C# code pads shorter keys with 0x00 values and truncates longer keys. Post test data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Topaco: I have updated the question with test data

Comment: @Topaco: So u saying the Java code is correct? In Java code if I make the IV as same as Key(like in c#), its giving "java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long"

Comment: Test data consists of key, plaintext and ciphertext. Without plaintext a repro is not possible. However, it does not look like the posted ciphertext was produced with the posted key and C# code since the decryption counterpart fails. Post the plaintext to check this.

Comment: Changing the padding is not changing the code.  It just make the java compatible with the c#.

Comment: Both codes use the same padding, so changing the padding is pointless. The C# code uses PKCS#7 padding, which in the Java world is called PKCs#5 padding, i.e. only the names differ, the padding algorithm is the same!

Comment: @Topaco: I have updated the plain text in the question and the cipher is generated from c# code and the key.

Comment: The posted data is inconsistent, i.e. with the posted plaintext and key, the posted ciphertext cannot be reproduced with the C#: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VaRUrq. Either the data is wrong or you are using a different C# code. Post data that is reproducible with the C# code!

Comment: @Topaco: I used the encrypted cipher from the url(dotnetfiddle.net/VaRUrq), and tried to decrypt in JAVA but still its giving same error as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Decrypting the ciphertext generated with the C# code on .NET Fiddle works with the Java code when using the correct key and IV. However, I will not go into detail until there is consistent test data for the C# code.
The only way I can explain this inconsistency is that you are using a different C# code than posted, otherwise why would the test data not fit? But without C# code, there is nothing to port. Sorry, I can't help you any further.

Comment: @Topaco: IF I use the cipher text as generated from the .NET Fiddle, then also I m getting the exception, then some issue in my JAVA code right?

Comment: @Topaco: You mentioned it works with correct Key and IV, this means below: ?
Key: TL3U2HAQJZ79F8O5X4CNW6S10IEKGPYB
IV: byte[] IV=new byte[16];

If I use the same as above, still I am facing the same issue as mentioned in Question